# Should I skip the Build stage on AWS CodePipeline for a backend NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, build, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I have written a backend NodeJS (Typescript) application (with connections to a database etc., the usual stuff), and successfully created a CodePipeline which pulls the sources on target EC2s, and then runs npm install & start.

A friend of mine pointed out that I skipped the Build stage, and I couldn't really come up with a valid explanation. I know I tried but finally gave up, but unfortunately I can't find the sources that justified doing so.

So my question is: are backend applications supposed to be built like the frontend ones? Are there any good resources on how to do it?

Also, what's the point of the Build stage? How is it really different from just pulling the sources & compiling them on the EC2 directly? Is it just to save compilation time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [this](https://codingwithmanny.medium.com/automating-nodejs-ts-deployments-with-codepipeline-to-elastic-beanstalk-79664321ab91) make any sense?

Comment: The tutorial just says to skip the build stage without any explanation, so it's not really helpful I'm afraid

Comment: Build stage often is used for testing your application, running unit tests. If you don't have then, then there is no need for a build stage in your case.

Answer (score 1):

As the name indicates, Build stage is for building binary/artifacts. For an example: Prior to ECS deployment, we need to build docker image and need to upload it to registry like ECR. Using CodeBuild (Build Stage) this docker image creation and uploading can be achieved. Then using a Deploy Stage deploy the docker image to ECS. Another example is building jar file for a Java application and upload it to S3 for deploying it to Lambda. In CodeBuild you can arrange the order of execution. First perform source code analysis then build creation then automated unit testing etc... Also please note that you can use build stage for deployment as well. There is no limitation. Consider the Java example. After creating the Jar file, CodeBuild upload it to S3 and then CodeBuild deploy this Jar file to the respective Lambda. Depends on your requirement you can skip or include the build stage.

```
Also, what's the point of the Build stage? How is it really different 
from just pulling the sources & compiling them on the EC2 directly? Is 
it just to save compilation time?
```

Reg your above point:

CodeBuild start a new docker container for each build. All build commands are executing inside this docker container(CodeBuild read one file called buildspec.yml. You need to add your build/deploy commands in buildspec.yml and need to maintain this file in your code repository. CodeBuild execute the commands mentioned in this file.) For your case, npm build commands will be executed inside this docker. Then it create the build and upload it to your EC2. After executing all the actions CodeBuild destroy this docker image.

By using this approach

1. You can track records of all your builds.
2. keep the EC2 clean. This approach avoid the installation of unnessasary packages in EC2.
3. Ease of installation and configuration of runtimes required for your build.

Comment: This is a good explanation of what the build stage is however it doesn't answer my question, which is: should I skip the build stage for a nodeJS backend application? It looks like pretty much all tutorials do so, but they don't provide any explanation for it. If the code is in Typescript, it must be compiled somehow: should I use the build stage to do that or should I just deploy on the EC2 and run npm start from the sources directly? Would it be any different for a frontend / web build?